# Prove that in affine geometry all triangles are congruent (using transformation groups )

Tags: group-theory

Let $GA_n(K) = Trans(K^n)\cdot GL_n(K)$ be a full affine group, where $Trans(K^n)$ is transitive transformation group of the space $K$.

(Book E.Vinberg."A Course in Algebra".: https://books.google.de/books?id=kd24d3mwaecC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=Vinberg+Prove+that+all+triangle+in+affine+geometry+are+congruent&source=bl&ots=Nao313bkGd&sig=yNYa-2k5Qcye_1dJAUHCFQhqr-A&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipnZq586DaAhXKZpoKHV5tBKoQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=Vinberg%20Prove%20that%20all%20triangle%20in%20affine%20geometry%20are%20congruent&f=false)

Could someone give idea how to prove it using Transformation GROUPS only, without geometry?

Comment: What? Isn't $\mathcal{Trans}$ rather the group of *translations*? Because, every affine transformation is a linear transformation plus a translation.

Comment: Sorry, used the wrong word..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first recall that the affine group $GA_{2}(K)$ is equal to $\text{GL}(2,K)\ltimes K^{2}$. In particular, an affine transformation $F\in GA_{2}(K)$ can be written as
\begin{equation}\label{def}
F:K^{2}\rightarrow K^{2}:p\mapsto Ap+b,\end{equation}
for unique $A\in\text{GL}(2,K)$ and $b\in K^{2}$.

Now, assume we are given two triangles with vertices $V_{0},V_{1},V_{2}$ and $W_{0},W_{1},W_{2}$ respectively. Then $V_{1}-V_{0}$ and $V_{2}-V_{0}$ are linearly independent, and so are $W_{1}-W_{0}$ and $W_{2}-W_{0}$. Hence there exists a unique linear transformation $A\in\text{GL}(2,K)$ satisfying

\begin{align*}
A(V_{1}-V_{0})=W_{1}-W_{0}\\
A(V_{2}-V_{0})=W_{2}-W_{0}.
\end{align*}

Now put $$b:=W_{0}-A(V_{0}).$$

Let $F$ be the affine transformation determined by $A$ and $b$ just defined. Then
$$
F(V_{0})=A(V_{0})+b=W_{0}$$
and
\begin{align*}
F(V_{1})&=F(V_{0})+F(V_{1})-F(V_{0})\\
&=W_{0}+A(V_{1})+b-(A(V_{0})+b)\\
&=W_{0}+A(V_{1}-V_{0})\\
&=W_{0}+(W_{1}-W_{0})\\
&=W_{1},
\end{align*}
and similarly $F(V_{2})=W_{2}$.